# want to get values from 2003 up to today

Tags: visual-studio-2013, sql-server-2014, ssrs-2012

```
DECLARE @year VARCHAR(100)

SET @year = '%-2003-%'

SELECT 
    DISTINCT 'AR Invoice', b.user_transaction_type_code as ar_transaction_type_code, b.name_l as ar_name_l, min(transaction_nr) as ar_min_tran_nr, max(transaction_nr) as ar_max_tran_nr, MIN(transaction_text) as min_ar_transaction_text, MAX(transaction_text) as max_ar_transaction_text
FROM
    ar_invoice a, user_transaction_type b
WHERE
    a.user_transaction_type_id = b.user_transaction_type_id AND
    transaction_text like @year
GROUP BY
    b.user_transaction_type_code, b.name_l
```

I want to get the values from 2003 up to today?
Can someone tell me how?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get values from 2003 to today, you can use `BETWEEN '2003-01-01' AND GETDATE()` option in the WHERE clause.

```
SELECT  DISTINCT 'AR Invoice', b.user_transaction_type_code AS ar_transaction_type_code, 
        b.name_l AS ar_name_l, min(transaction_nr) AS ar_min_tran_nr, max(transaction_nr) AS ar_max_tran_nr, 
        MIN(transaction_text) AS min_ar_transaction_text, MAX(transaction_text) AS max_ar_transaction_text
FROM ar_invoice a
INNER JOIN user_transaction_type b ON b.user_transaction_type_id = a.user_transaction_type_id
WHERE transaction_text BETWEEN '2003-01-01' AND GETDATE()
GROUP BY b.user_transaction_type_code, b.name_l
```

Comment: UV from me but I bet they are using `varchar` on `transaction_text` so you may want to include that

Answer (score 0):

DECLARE @year VARCHAR(100)

SET @year = @FromYear --2003 --today

SELECT DISTINCT 'AR Invoice'

, b.user_transaction_type_code as ar_transaction_type_code
, b.name_l as ar_name_l                                                          , min(transaction_nr) as ar_min_tran_nr
, max(transaction_nr) as ar_max_tran_nr
, MIN(transaction_text) as min_ar_transaction_text
, MAX(transaction_text) as max_ar_transaction_text

FROM
    ar_invoice a, user_transaction_type b

WHERE
    a.user_transaction_type_id = b.user_transaction_type_id 
AND
    transaction_text like '%'+'-'+ @year +'-' + '%'

GROUP BY
    b.user_transaction_type_code, b.name_l